# Получение номера телефона после отправки его в telegram

Tags: python, telegram, бот, aiogram

У меня есть функция для отправки номера телефона

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['phonenumber'])
    def phone(message):
        keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1, resize_keyboard=True)
        button_phone = types.KeyboardButton(text="Отправить телефон",
                                            request_contact=True)
        keyboard.add(button_phone)
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Номер телефона',
                         reply_markup=keyboard)
```

Как мне его получить? В дальнейшем я буду с ним работать
В telebot это можно сделать следующим образом

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
def contact(message):
    if message.contact is not None:
        keyboard2 = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы успешно отправили свой номер', reply_markup=keyboard2)
        global phonenumber
        phonenumber= str(message.contact.phone_number)
        user_id = str(message.contact.user_id)
```

Как это сделать в aiogram?
Пробую

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
def contact(message):
    if message.contact is not None:
        keyboard2 = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы успешно отправили свой номер', reply_markup=keyboard2)
        global phonenumber
        phonenumber= str(message.contact.phone_number)
        user_id = str(message.contact.user_id)
```

Далее мне необходимо сделать следующее

```
try:
    user = users.objects.get(user_id=user_id)
    print(user)
except users.DoesNotExist:
    telegram = users
    telegram(user_id=user_id, phonenumber=phonenumber).save()
```

Но я получаю сообщение Task exception was never retrieved
Если тоже самое делать через telebot, то данный код работает. В моём случае выдаётся данное сообщение но при этом в переменных содержится номер телефона и id пользователя

Comment: Aiogram -- асинхронная библиотека. Это значит, что все хендлеры нужно объявлять, как асинхронные функции -- с использованием ключевого слова async. А вызывать библиотечные функции нужно с помощью ключевого слова await.

Comment: Куда мне это нужно добавить? Я не совсем понимаю. Можете подсказать пожалуйста?

Comment: это очень большая тема для объяснения, и я советую вам выучить основы языка программирования, прежде чем пользоваться им. Вот здесь вы можете найти документацию модуля asyncio: https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html. Вот здесь статья на хабре с неплохим описанием асинхронности в питоне: https://habr.com/ru/post/337420/.

Comment: а возможно ли сделать также через router?

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте вот так.

```py
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['contact'])
async def contact(message):
    if message.contact is not None:
        keyboard2 = types.ReplyKeyboardRemove()
        await bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Вы успешно отправили свой номер', reply_markup=keyboard2)
        global phonenumber
        phonenumber= str(message.contact.phone_number)
        user_id = str(message.contact.user_id)
```

Comment: А как условие написать если человек нажал отмену? у меня что то не получается